# Where does Windows store the list of users?

Tags: windows, user-accounts

Linux, for example stores users in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow`.

Where does Windows store them? I don't think there is a file. Maybe an internal Database? Do you have any documents from Microsoft about it? I didn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Account Details are Stored in [SAM Registry Hives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Accounts_Manager).
SAM or Security Accounts Management stores the LM/NTLM password hashes. It is located in

> %windir%\system32\config\sam

SAM file cannot be accessed by underprivileged users. However, some third party tools can access it.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to find the official Microsoft documentation about this topic: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457114.aspx